# SQL select statement to get calculated column from second row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have table like this

```
c1   c2 
25   30
42   28
50   15
```

how to get the table like below using sql select statement

```
c1  c2    c3   c4
25  30    0    0
42  28    -3   45  
50  15   27   33
```

-3 came from 25-28 & 45 came from 42-(-3)
i have to do calculations using previous row

Comment: What have you tried so far? What determines the ordering, is it `c1` ascending or do you have another ID field that can be used to determine 'previous' row?  Also, which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: i am using sql2005 server and i have primary Id

Comment: sql server 2005 doesnt have the lag or lead functions use self join with subquery where t.id<.t1.id

Comment: please let me know the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to get previous record, since `LAG` is not available in SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT t.*, COALESCE(t1.c1 - t.c2, 0) AS c3, COALESCE(t.c1 - (t1.c1 - t.c2), 0) AS c4
FROM @T AS t
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 *
   FROM @T
   WHERE id < t.id
   ORDER BY id DESC
) t1
ORDER BY t.id
```

With this as input:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT, c1 INT, c2 INT)

INSERT @T VALUES
(1, 25, 30),
(2, 42, 28),
(3, 50, 15)
```

you get this output:

```
id  c1  c2  c3  c4
-------------------
1   25  30  0   0
2   42  28  -3  45
3   50  15  27  23
```

In case your table does not have an auto-increment id as PK, then you can sort by c1 instead (if this is what really satisfies your requirements for *previous* record).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Using `Left Join` and `Row_Number()` you can get the result. There is a mistake in your expected output in last column the last row value should be `23` not `33` because you have said `C4=C1-c3` so 50-27 should be `23` not `33`

```
CREATE TABLE #t
  (c1 INT,c2 INT)

INSERT #t
VALUES( 25,30),
       (42,28),
       (50,15);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY c1) rn,*
         FROM   #t)
SELECT a.c1,a.c2,
       Isnull(CASE WHEN b.rn IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT c1 FROM cte
                                               WHERE  rn = a.rn - 1) - a.c2
              END, 0)            c3,
       Isnull(a.c1 - ( CASE WHEN b.rn IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT c1 FROM   cte
                                                        WHERE  rn = a.rn - 1) - a.c2
                       END ), 0) c4
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b ON a.rn = b.rn + 1
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
c1  c2  c3  c4
--  --  --  --
25  30  0   0
42  28  -3  45
50  15  27  23
```